# Is it possible to convert a C++ struct's fields to a pack parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, struct, typelist

I have a struct like below:

```
struct A1
{
   int a;
   int b;

   char c[10];
};
```

or

```
struct A2
{
   double t;    
   char* p;
};
```

And now I want to access all filed, My leader suggest me to use pack parameter to handle this simply, just like this:

```
template<typename... T>
void handler(T...args)
{
   // handle all struct fileds, such a, b, c here
}
```

// how to call it?

```
A1 a1;    
handle(a1);

A2 a2;    
handle(a2);
```

Sadly, I have no idea about that how to access all fields one by one?

> Please note  that the template function should be general for we don't
>   know how the struct is defined?

Is it possible? if yes, Could you please show me you idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you should ask your leader how he envisions generically handling all member variables. I can't think of a standard compliant way to do that. Maybe somebody more knowledgeable than me does.

Comment: In c++17 you have so called structure bindings, but it still doesn't let you bind to any fields number and the number must be known beforehand...

Comment: Your leader may be thinking of [magic_get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer is **no**.

A [paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1061r0.html) proposing a way to do this (via structured bindings) has been written, but it won't be considered until at least [November](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/n4715.pdf).